# Skipping oversized inputs when using fgets(3)

Tags: c, fgets

this is probably quite easy to figure out, maybe i'm just looking in the wrong places, but how does one test if fgets has read an oversized input? In the code below, i'm trying to skip further processing for empty lines and oversized ones and go straight to the next line, for empty lines it works just fine.
Printing the strlen(buffer) when using line lengths < `maxsize` and it gives me expected values.

However when i enter lines that exceed the maxsize, it prints a value over 9000, which should still exceed the `maxsize`, and therefore enter the if-clause, but this doesn't happen. I've tried casting the return value of strlen into an `int`, didn't work.

What am i missing here? Thanks for any replies :)

```
char buffer[102];
while (fgets(buffer,100,stdin)!=NULL){
            size_t maxsize = 102;
            printf("%ld",strlen(buffer));
            if(strcmp(buffer,"\n")==0||strlen(buffer)>maxsize){
            continue;
            }
            //further processing        
        }
```

I

Comment: [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) returns a [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t), for which the proper format specifier is [`%zu`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: If the line doesnt fit, the last character wont be `\n` (before the `\0`. And you don't need strlen(), at least not in this way. It's all in the Fine Manual)

Comment: Good read: http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/c/getting_input.html

Comment: Thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 0):

in the code:

```
char buffer[102];
while (fgets(buffer,100,stdin)!=NULL){
```

You don't need to give two more characters to `buffer`.  The parameter size of `fgets` just can be the application of the `sizeof` operator, as in:

```
char buffer[102];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {
```

That will give you space for lines of up to 101 characters (to leave space to the string terminator) including (or not, see below) the new line character.

But, answering your question, I understand that you want to know what happens if your input in one line is indeed bigger that the buffer size you provided, what happens then to the input, and how `fgets` deal with this:

`Fgets()` reads as many characters as it finds a `\n` in the input, or the buffer fills completely (this is, after including the `\0` character that it must append to the string to terminate it)  So, `fgets()` will fill as many characters in the buffer as the buffer has, minus one, reserved for the null string terminator, *and the rest of the line will be read in the next `fgets()` (or another call to any of the functions of the stdio package).*

So, basically, lines longer than one less than the buffer size are split in pieces, in which all except the last don't actually end in a new line, and the last will have the new line included, and will be shorter, all with a length of the length you specified minus one, but the last piece, in which the length is what it requires (again, always less than or equal than the length specified minus one)